# Command: sudo su -

Tags: unix, bash, sudo, su

I understand what `su -` does

- logs you into root with the root environment
- (as opposed to `su` which logs you into root with your environment)

And I understand what `sudo` does

- you are root for one command

But I am unsure what this does: `sudo su -`

Anyone care to clarify

Comment: What do you mean by environment?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In addition to what you said, `su` requires the root password and `sudo` requires your user password

Therefore `sudo su -` will put you into a root environment but it will ask you for your user password instead of the root password (once sudo has given you root privileges, `su -` can be executed with no password).

Comment: +1 good explanation.  If I config my sudo can I make it not require a password?  That would made su require 'no password'?

Comment: note that `sudo -i` is a somewhat more direct way of doing the same thing

Answer (score 7):

If you are allowed (configuration of sudo) to use the `su` command, it asks you for **your** password and then logs you in as root.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you will get a root shell.

Long answer: it is different from doing 'su -' within a root shell. Once you exit (eg., Ctrl-D) from 'sudo su -', the execution of sudo will end.

Observed on Debian Wheezy with htop:

'sudo su -' has a child of 'su -', and 'su -' has a child of '-su'.

As mentioned above, root user can do 'su -' without entering password, so doing 'su -' inside of a root shell, you will have two different root shell processes. ending the inner one will let you return back to the outer one.