# What's the difference between sudo su - and sudo -i?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo, su

It is my understanding that they do the same: they ask for my password (if I am allowed in /etc/sudoers), and give me a login shell as root.

Is there any difference between them?

```
sudo su -
sudo -i
```

Also, what's the difference between

```
sudo su
sudo -s
```

I think that they both ask for my password, and give me a shell with my old environment variables.

Comment: Also see <http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i>, and <http://superuser.com/questions/105367/command-sudo-su>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is little difference in the command pairs you are wondering about.

The first pair attempts to simulate a fresh login as the new user-- there could be some difference in the environmental variables supplied, as `sudo su -` is going to try and preserve existing environmental variables, while `sudo -i` will set very specific environmental variables and strip all others (check your man pages for specifics).

For the second pair, the difference in behavior is this: `sudo su` will always start the shell listed in the user's `/etc/passwd`, whereas `sudo -s` will check the `SHELL` environmental variable first, and only execute the shell in `/etc/passwd` if `SHELL` is unset.

Comment: Note that the set of variables preserved by "`su -`"/"`sudo su -`" is also very restricted, maybe similar to what `sudo -i` does.

Comment: `sudo su -` _is going to try and preserve existing environmental variables_ ? I read that `su -` _makes the shell a login shell_ **&** _changes the environmental variables to those of the new user_ [source](http://superuser.com/a/453989/140711)