# What's the difference between "su" with and without hyphen?

Tags: linux, su

I'm quite new to Linux terminal and I'm not quite sure what the difference between `su` with a hyphen and `su` without a hyphen is, for example: `su - username` vs. `su username`.

I looked [into the documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) but in there, this was not mentioned. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: a "login shell" often means interactive shell. This is vs. a shell that just executes a script and exits.

Comment: It's right there in the [same manpage you link to](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su): "*-, -l, --login: make the shell a login shell*"

Comment: you don't even have to google it, just type `su --help`.

Comment: Of noteworthyness: This is particularly useful when su-ing to root as without using the hypen to start a new login shell, your `$PATH` won't get updated and thus you won't be able to directly call root-only binaries in `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`

Answer (score 126):

The difference between "-" and "no hyphen" is that the latter *keeps* your existing environment (variables, etc); the former creates a new environment (with the settings of the actual user, not your own).

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Su
>
> The hyphen has two effects:
>
> 1)  switches from the current directory to the home directory of the
>   new user (e.g., to /root in the case of the root user) by logging in
>   as that user
>
> 2) changes the environmental variables to those of the new user as
>   dictated by their ~/.bashrc. That is, if the first argument to su is a
>   hyphen, the current directory and environment will be changed to what
>   would be expected if the new user had actually logged on to a new
>   session (rather than just taking over an existing session).

Comment: this site -> http://www.admon.org/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/ says that when used without the hyphen the files /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile are not executed. What significance do these two files have on the user environment ?

Comment: Those two things are the files that *set* the user environment :)  *Not* executing them means *keeping* your original environment.  Executing them (by using "-") means making *your* environment the same as the user you're "su'ing" to.  Using the hyphen is usually what you *want* - I use "-"  habitually whenever I "su".

Comment: does the order of execution really matter ? Iam asking this because on that site they have mentioned that the two files /etc/bashrc
~/.bashrc are executed in reverse order when in a non login shell. Somebody please help me

Comment: @user574183 of course, e.g. if one set something but the other unset something or set to something else

Answer (score 8):

**Year 2022 update:**

It is discouraged shorthand for `--login`.

See: https://man.archlinux.org/man/su.1#DESCRIPTION

> It is recommended to always use the --login option (instead of its
> shortcut -) to avoid side effects caused by mixing environments.

And https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Su :

> You will sometimes encounter su being used to get a login shell with
> su -, rather than su -l/su --login. This shorthand is discouraged
> because the - option can encounter parsing limitations.

Comment: What are the kinds of problems one could experience by using `su -` instead of `su --login`? Unfortunately neither the wiki nor man page provides examples.