# environment using su - vs "ssh user@machine" as a user on lucid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh

I'm trying to debug a shell environment issue on a machine running lucid.

Both root & user have /bin/bash as their shell in /etc/passwd
When I use "sudo su - user", my PATH includes the following directory: 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
when I "ssh user@machine" it has: 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

Now, there are probably a number of ruby/rvm specific answers here -- that's not what I'm looking for, what I'm trying to understand is the general problem of where to look to find whatever it is that is setting the path.  I know that /etc/profile gets executed, but it is being executed in both cases so I'm not sure what the issue is -- are there some other files that also get loaded on login -- in 1 case but not the other? / anything else that is being loaded that could be setting the PATH?

So it appears that something is happening before /etc/profile is loaded.  I echo'd the environment on the first line of /etc/profile, and in the ssh case, the path already included a reference to /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin -- in the sudo su - case it did not.  It appears that /etc/environment is used in the ssh case, but not the sudo su - case...

One other thing I found recently that is also relevant, from:
[What's the difference between "su" with and without hyphen?](https://superuser.com/questions/453988/whats-the-difference-between-su-with-and-without-hyphen)

the /etc/login.defs file gets used when doing su, and the /etc/environment PATH setting is overwritten by the ENV_PATH or ENV_SUPATH in there...

one clarification
/etc/profile is used for login shells, but not non-login shells -- so, e.g.
sudo env
does not show variables that are set in /etc/profile only

while logging into an account will not show up variables that are set in /etc/environment only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably due to the difference between login and interactive shells. See [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile) for a nice summary.

The first file the system reads to set variables is `/etc/environment`. After that, which files are read depends on the way that bash has been invoked. When you `ssh user@machine`, you start a **login shell** but when you `su username`, you start an **interactive, non-login shell**. Bash will read its initialization settings from different files in each case. The following is from the bash man page (emphasis mine):

> When  bash  is  invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, **it first  reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, 
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order**, and reads and executes
>   commands from the first one that  exists  and  is readable.   The 
>   --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When  an  interactive  shell  that  is  not  a  login shell is
>   started,   **bash   reads    and    executes    commands    from
>   /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,**  if these files exist.  This may be
>   inhibited by using the  --norc  option.   The  --rcfile file  option
>   will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>   /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

So, bash reads different start up files depending on its invocation. Have a look at the contents of these files in your machine, you will probably find `$PATH` is being defined in different ways.

That said, as @mpy correctly pointed out in the comments, `sudo su - user` should start a login shell. Are you *sure* you are using `sudo su -` and not simple `sudo su` or just `su`? The `-` should start a login shell which should read exactly the same start up files as `ssh user`.

Comment: But shouldn't `su - user` also start a _login_ shell?

Comment: @mpy yes, quite right, I hadn't noticed the OP was using `-`.

Comment: right -- when I su without the -, the effect is the same as when I ssh -- it uses the older version of ruby.  Sounds like the files should be the same, so I'll keep digging.

Comment: Thanks for the info on include order -- if you'll edit your answer to include an /etc/environment reference, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @KemMason done. Never thought to include it since it is read before everything else and should be the same no matter how you start your shell.

Comment: `su - user` reads both bash_profile and bashrc, even though bashrc isn't sourced from the profile.