# sudo su and sudo -i-u dont work as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, su, ulimit

I am migrating one of our servers from centos 7 to ubutnu 22.4 lts

Found an interesting issue:

set /etc/security/limits.conf is set set with:

```
* soft core unlimited
* hard core unlimited
```

created new user named AAA,

code i am trying to run inside python3 shell (as AAA):

```
import resource
resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CORE)
resource.setrlimit(
    resource.RLIMIT_CORE,
        (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY)
    )
```

when login to the user using the command:
**sudo su AAA**
the code works and i can set core dump to unlimited

when login to the user with:
**sudo -i -u AAA /bin/bash**

the python code fails, user dont have permission

*I am editing it because it tagged as [duplication](https://superuser.com/questions/105367/command-sudo-su). reason why it is not:
Setting the security settings in limits.conf, both method (sudo su and sudo -i -u should give the same result)*